# Pandas: summing nanoseconds time delta to timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timedelta

This seems somehow a simple question, but I could not find answers to it (maybe using wrong search keywords):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Timestamp(1) + pd.Timedelta(seconds=1e-9)
Out: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001')  # why? Un-intuitive

pd.Timestamp(1) + pd.Timedelta(microseconds=1e-3)
Out: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001')  # why? Un-intuitive

pd.Timestamp(1) + pd.Timedelta(nanoseconds=1)
Out: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002')  # ok, but not consistent with above ones
```

Even if timestamps being based on the epoch in nanoseconds would be the argument, then why this (eg) inconsistency:

```
pd.Timestamp(1) + pd.Timedelta(seconds=1e-9)
Out: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001')

pd.Timestamp(1) + pd.Timedelta(seconds=1e-6)
Out: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001001')
```

Comment: Timedelta same as datetime in python https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: @BENY pandas Timedelta has a nanoseconds attribute while native Python's timedelta does not - the latter only supports precision down to microseconds. So compatibility only **can** go that far; they are not exactly the same I think. The "un-intuitive" part starts at that level: precision higher than microseconds; `pd.Timedelta(seconds=1e-6)` is correctly converted to 1 µs while `pd.Timedelta(seconds=1e-9)` *is not* converted to 1 ns as one might expect - in fact, it's just ignored.

Comment: btw. I went through some pandas source code, but could exactly determine the place where this goes wrong. You could submit an issue on their github; [there already are many](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+timedelta) of them evolving around timedelta ;-)

Comment: I also investigated the source code a bit before publishing the question, with the same result as you. Tks.

Comment: Submitted potential bug [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43764)

Comment: @MrFuppes tagging you. Bug solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and was fixed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/45108).

Comment: already checked out in pd dev version, great work! Currently (2022-01-17), this fix is not yet part of the release version (1.3.5).